# Celery's @shared_task not working with soft_time_limit

Tags: python, celery, gevent

Here's some simple code:

```
@shared_task(time_limit=10, soft_time_limit=5)
def check_action():
    try:
        __import__("time").sleep(100)
    except celery.exceptions.SoftTimeLimitExceeded as e:
        print("Here", e, type(e))
    except BaseException as e:
        print("There", e, type(e))
```

It's a `shared_task` with `time_limit` and `soft_time_limit` set up, so I expect `Here` to be printed after 5 seconds (along with `SoftTimeLimitExceeded` exception info) and then `There` to be printed with some hard-timeout exception.

Instead, it doesn't raise `SoftTimeLimitExceeded` at all, only hard time limit is called, full output is:

```
celery_1               | [2019-05-31 21:36:36,709: WARNING/MainProcess] There
celery_1               | [2019-05-31 21:36:36,710: WARNING/MainProcess] 10 seconds
celery_1               | [2019-05-31 21:36:36,710: WARNING/MainProcess] <class 'gevent.timeout.Timeout'>
```

As it can be seen from logs, I use `gevent` workers, if it's of any help.

**UPD #1:** the problems seems to be with `gevent` pool (is I remove `--pool=gevent`, everything works perfectly).

**UPD #2:** `eventlet` pool doesn't seem to support any timeout, even the hard one.

Answer (score 2):

It really is the problem with `gevent` pool, as mentioned in [this](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2061) pull request.

Question can be considered closed.